# CSS selector for only-child and no other non-space character siblings

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
code {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  color: red;
}
p > code:only-child {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 125%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>Assuming you have the IP <code>1.1.1.1</code>:</p>

<p><code>
echo "hello world";
echo "another command here";
echo "you are done";
</code></p>
</body></html>
```

But it's causing the page to look like this:

[image]

The problem is that the `p > code:only-child` is also selecting the `<code>1.1.1.1</code>`.  What is the CSS rule to select a `<code>` element if and only if it is an only child element and it does not have any non-space character sibling?

---

Note: I am not able to edit HTML because it's been created by another software I don't have access too. I am also not allowed to use JavaScript.   I only have authority to add my own CSS code.

I have about 1000 other HTML documents like this where there is a `<p>some text<code>/etc/path-to-conf</code>some text</p>` and others that are `<p>text<code>...</code>text<code>...</code>...</p>` and others that are `<p><code>...</code></p>`.  I don't want to manually go through each html document one at a time to write a custom css selector.  Only when `<code>` element is only child element without non-space character siblings should appear as a block level element. All other `<code>` elements should appear as inline-block.

Comment: If your HTML structure is fixed, why not using some other ways to target the `<code>` block you want? Such as `p:last-child > code` etc.

Comment: I have 1000 other html pages each with different HTML structure. I don't want to go to each 1000 page one at a time and write a specific rule `p:last-child` or `p:nth-child(...)`  . I want 1 css rule that can apply globally on all 1000 pages.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe like this:**

```css
 p:has(code) code {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <code>1.1.1.1</code>
    <p>HELLO <code>1.1.1.1</code>
        <span>ONE <code>two</code></span>
    </p>
    <p>WORLD <code>1.1.1.1</code></p>
    <code>1.1.1.1</code>

    <p>1.1.1.1</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is functioning correctly. It selects code in both instances as there are no other elements present aside from the code. If you believe this might pose an issue, consider using:

```
<p><span>Assuming you have the IP</span><code>1.1.1.1</code>:</p>
```

This modification introduces a  element alongside  within the paragraph for potential adjustments.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! But I am unable to edit the HTML.  It is generated by another tool that I don't have access too.  I also can't write javascript code.

Comment: If modifying the HTML or JavaScript is not possible, you can utilize the following CSS.
```
    code {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      color: red;
    }
    
    p:last-child code {
      display: block;
      white-space: pre;
      padding: 20px;
      line-height: 125%;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 1em 0;
    }
```

Comment: your solution will work for just this one example. I have about 1000 other pages where the `p` tag may not be the final item on the page. I don't wnat to go to 1000 pages and run custom css rules for each page. Is there one rule that I can apply that works for all 1000 pages?

Comment: Can you provide some different code examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no way to use only CSS targeting an element that doesn't have any siblings counting [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text).

However, if you're able to add a `<script>` tag the same way the `<style>` tag is added, this would be possible with some JavaScript.

If that's not an option, then you may want to modify how the HTML is generated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    code {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      color: red;
      font-family: ui-monospace,"Cascadia Mono","Segoe UI Mono","Liberation Mono",Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;
    }
    
    .code-block {
      display: block;
      white-space: pre;
      padding: 20px;
      line-height: 1.25;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 1em 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      [...document.querySelectorAll('p > code')].filter(code => 
        code.parentElement.childNodes.length === 1
      ).forEach(code => code.classList.add('code-block'));
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Assuming you have the IP <code>1.1.1.1</code>:</p>

  <p><code>
echo "hello world";
echo "another command here";
echo "you are done";
</code></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get exactly what is required using CSS but you can get closer (getting the IP address on the same line as the text and making it black) by selecting ::first-line of the code element.

This works for the code given to produce:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    code {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0;
      color: red;
    }
    
    p>code:only-child {
      white-space: pre;
      padding: 20px;
      line-height: 125%;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 1em 0;
    }
    
    p>code:only-child::first-line {
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Assuming you have the IP <code>1.1.1.1</code>:</p>

  <p><code>
echo "hello world";
echo "another command here";
echo "you are done";
</code></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: it works as shown because there is a blank line in the actual code block so the first echo line is not selected.